# How to develop a function to open a csv file without using python libraries

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a function to read a single specified column of data from a CSV file without using any libraries in python.

```
def my_task1_file(filename):
    filename = open(task1.csv)
    for my_file in filename:
        print(my_file.split(',')[1])

my_task1_file
```

Comment: The function should work, you need to call it with an argument.

Comment: You should close the file when done. The best way to do this is using the `with` statement.

Comment: You should strip the newline off the end of the line in case you're reading the last column.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: `task1.csv` needs to be quoted if it should be a literal string. But you should presumably be using the `filename` parameter, not putting a specific filename in the function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are just replacing `filename` with new `filename` which wont work. Try using this:

```
def my_task1_file(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for my_file in f.readlines():
            print(my_file.split(',')[1])

my_task1_file('task1.csv')
```

Answer (score -1):

To start building an answer from [Barmar's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70509931/how-to-develop-a-function-to-open-a-csv-file-without-using-python-libraries#comment124639853_70509931):

```py
def my_task1_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:  # the with statement to open/close files safely
        for line in f.readlines():  # read all lines using file-handle f
            fields = line.split(',')  # split each line by comma into fields
            print(fields)  # print all field read


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_task1_file('task1.csv')  # call the function with a filename or path
```

#### Some issues in your code

The variable names have been chosen misleading (might be part of the task to figure out and improve):

- `filename` in your code was (a) the parameter, (b) the file-handle returned by `open()`
- `my_file` was an iteration variable holding each line read from the file
- `my_file.split(',')` splits each line by comma into fields, returns a list of fields
- the second element or field (`[1]`) of returned list was printed `my_file.split(',')[1]`

The function call in Python should be written with parentheses: not `function` but `function()` or `function(argument)`